# dbcontext and reseting elements in memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to write some unit tests for some open source code.

one of the tests will test that only the minimal number of records have been loaded to memory
(ie if someone were to call:

```
 DataContext.SomeTable.ToList().Where(s=>s.Id <=10)
```

the test should fail)

For this to work, DataContext.SomeTable.Load should be reset to have 0 items before the unit test executes.

At present, this TestFixture (using nunit, but that should not be relevant) is abstract, with the DbContext injected at instantiation, so that unit tests can test different providers.
I don't believe there is a way to clear the loaded entities, but was wondering how I might dispose and create a new DbContext which uses the same database provider as the injected context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, could you post your code?

Second, if I understand correctly, you would like to re-create the context every time?  One solution is to pass in a function to create the context instead of the context itself.  Like this:

```
public class MyTest {

    private Func<IMyContext> createContext;

    public MyTest(Func<IMyContext> createContext){
       this.createContext = createContext;
    }

    [Test]
    public void RunTest(){
        using(var context = this.createContext()){
             // do stuff with context
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestClass
{
    private MyContext context;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        // is executed before each test
        context = new MyContext();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()

        context.SomeTable.ToList().Where(s => s.Id <= 10);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Complete()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }

}
```

each test should access table only once.
point of unit tests is that each test is for single scenario.